# Accidentally changed vimrc encoding to utf-16

Tags: vim, character-encoding

I was editing my `.vimrc`, and I `set` `encoding` and `fileencoding` to `utf-16` out of curiosity. I saved and quit the file, and now my `.vimrc` looks like this.

How can I restore my `.vimrc` to default encoding and get back my VIM settings? I'm on macOS 12.4.

```
^@"^@ ^@V^@I^@M^@-^@P^@L^@U^@G^@
^@c^@a^@l^@l^@ ^@p^@l^@u^@g^@#^@b^@e^@g^@i^@n^@(^@'^@~^@/^@.^@v^@i^@m^@/^@p^@l^@u^@g^@g^@e^@d^@'^@)^@
^@ ^@ ^@ ^@ ^@P^@l^@u^@g^@ ^@'^@j^@u^@n^@e^@g^@u^@n^@n^@/^@f^@z^@f^@'^@,^@ ^@{^@ ^@'^@d^@o^@'^@:^@ ^@{^@ ^@-^@>^@ ^@f^@z^@f^@#^@i^@n^@s^@t^@a^@l^@l^@(^@)^@ ^@}^@ ^@}^@
^@ ^@ ^@ ^@ ^@P^@l^@u^@g^@ ^@'^@j^@u^@n^@e^@g^@u^@n^@n^@/^@f^@z^@f^@.^@v^@i^@m^@'^@
^@ ^@ ^@ ^@ ^@P^@l^@u^@g^@ ^@'^@v^@i^@m^@-^@a^@i^@r^@l^@i^@n^@e^@/^@v^@i^@m^@-^@a^@i^@r^@l^@i^@n^@e^@'^@
^@ ^@ ^@ ^@ ^@P^@l^@u^@g^@ ^@'^@v^@i^@m^@-^@a^@i^@r^@l^@i^@n^@e^@/^@v^@i^@m^@-^@a^@i^@r^@l^@i^@n^@e^@-^@t^@h^@e^@m^@e^@s^@'^@
^@c^@a^@l^@l^@ ^@p^@l^@u^@g^@#^@e^@n^@d^@(^@)^@
^@
^@s^@y^@n^@t^@a^@x^@ ^@o^@n^@
^@s^@e^@t^@ ^@t^@e^@r^@m^@g^@u^@i^@c^@o^@l^@o^@r^@s^@
^@s^@e^@t^@ ^@b^@a^@c^@k^@g^@r^@o^@u^@n^@d^@=^@d^@a^@r^@k^@
^@c^@o^@l^@o^@r^@s^@c^@h^@e^@m^@e^@ ^@b^@r^@o^@g^@r^@a^@m^@m^@e^@r^@
^@l^@e^@t^@ ^@g^@:^@a^@i^@r^@l^@i^@n^@e^@_^@t^@h^@e^@m^@e^@=^@'^@m^@i^@n^@i^@m^@a^@l^@i^@s^@t^@'^@
^@
^@s^@e^@t^@ ^@e^@n^@c^@o^@d^@i^@n^@g^@=^@u^@t^@f^@-^@1^@6^@
^@s^@e^@t^@ ^@f^@i^@l^@e^@e^@n^@c^@o^@d^@i^@n^@g^@=^@u^@t^@f^@-^@1^@6^@
^@
^@s^@e^@t^@ ^@n^@u^@m^@b^@e^@r^@
^@s^@e^@t^@ ^@r^@e^@l^@a^@t^@i^@v^@e^@n^@u^@m^@b^@e^@r^@
^@s^@e^@t^@ ^@t^@a^@b^@s^@t^@o^@p^@=^@4^@ ^@s^@o^@f^@t^@t^@a^@b^@s^@t^@o^@p^@=^@4^@
^@s^@e^@t^@ ^@s^@h^@i^@f^@t^@w^@i^@d^@t^@h^@=^@4^@
^@s^@e^@t^@ ^@e^@x^@p^@a^@n^@d^@t^@a^@b^@
^@s^@e^@t^@ ^@s^@m^@a^@r^@t^@i^@n^@d^@e^@n^@t^@
^@s^@e^@t^@ ^@c^@u^@r^@s^@o^@r^@l^@i^@n^@e^@
^@s^@e^@t^@ ^@s^@c^@r^@o^@l^@l^@o^@f^@f^@=^@8^@
^@s^@e^@t^@ ^@h^@l^@s^@e^@a^@r^@c^@h^@
^@s^@e^@t^@ ^@i^@g^@n^@o^@r^@e^@c^@a^@s^@e^@
^@s^@e^@t^@ ^@i^@n^@c^@s^@e^@a^@r^@c^@h^@
^@s^@e^@t^@ ^@t^@t^@i^@m^@e^@o^@u^@t^@l^@e^@n^@=^@0^@
^@s^@e^@t^@ ^@s^@p^@e^@l^@l^@ ^@s^@p^@e^@l^@l^@l^@a^@n^@g^@=^@e^@n^@_^@u^@s^@
^@
^@l^@e^@t^@ ^@m^@a^@p^@l^@e^@a^@d^@e^@r^@ ^@=^@ ^@'^@ ^@'^@ ^@
^@
^@i^@n^@o^@r^@e^@m^@a^@p^@ ^@j^@k^@ ^@<^@E^@S^@C^@>^@
```

Comment: You saved as UTF-16 so you have an UTF-16 file. In any case, your question is probably off-topic. This site is about programming (we can argue that `vim` is for programmer and not for normal users). In any case we have various sister sites for such questions (see links on top right icon). "Superuser" or "Unix & Linux" may be more relevant

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Yes, how do I restore it to default encoding and restore my settings in `.vimrc`?

Comment: How can you not know what encoding it is after explicitly setting the encoding to utf-16?

Comment: Simple way: rename the file, so that vim will not use it (and so you have sane default), then read that file and convert to UTF-8, and then you can restore the original name. `iconv` command is an other method, but if you are used to vim, the first may be quicker -- and I forgot: remove the part where you save files to UTF-16. We are in a better world then the nearly obsolete UTF-16 world

Comment: @romainl Thanks. I've edited the question for better relevance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In shell command line (run `vim` without any configs):

```
vim -u NONE ~/.vimrc
```

In `vim` command line:

```
:edit ++enc=utf-16
:set fileencoding=ascii " or utf-8
:x " save and exit
```

Verify:

```
vim ~/.vimrc # or any other fie
```

(open any file using fixed `~/.vimrc` as the config file).